# Regexp for excluding line containing string from rest of the regexp

Tags: regex, operators

I have bunch of strings like:

```
object field: TMemo
  Left = 6
  Top = 23
  Width = 390
  Height = 156
  Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
  ScrollBars = ssVertical
  TabOrder = 1
  OnChange = fieldChange
  OnKeyUp = fieldKeyUp
  AddMenu = True
  RightClickMoveCaret = True
  RightEdge = 0
end
```

Or

```
object btn: TButton
  Left = 5
  Top = 3
  Width = 89
  Height = 21
  Caption = 'Button'
  TabOrder = 0
  TabStop = False
  OnClick = btnClick
end
```

I want to select all text except name of object (in this case field and btn) and every line that starts with [space][space]On.

I can select everything without name of field using regexp like this:

```
(object)|(: .*)|(end)|(  .*)
```

But I'm not able deselect lines starting with "On".
Can you help me join my regexp with this regexp excluding this lines I want from selection?:

```
(^(?:(?!  On).)*$)
```

Comment: Try using a negative lookahead `(?!  On)(  .*)` or `^(?!  On)(  .*)` like `(object)|(: .*)|(end)|(?!  On)(  .*)` https://regex101.com/r/GUyTQG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!  On)(  .*)` for the last alternation to check what is on the right is not 2 spaces followed by On:

```
(object)|(: .*)|(end)|(?!  On)(  .*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUyTQG/1)

Since your matches are at the start and the end of the stirng, a more precise match might be using  anchors `^` and `$`:

```
^(object)|(: .*)$|^(end)$|^(?!  On)(  .*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaB3Jw/1)

Note that you can also get the matches without using capturing groups:

```
^object|: .*$|^end$|^(?!  On)  .*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (maybe)

```
^(?!On.*$).*
```